# Use smb share also as docker volume

Tags: docker, file-permissions, server-message-block

I've one Debian 11 Server which has multiple smb-shares under `/samba/`.
Now I'd like to run multiple instances of a file synchronisation software called Syncthing inside docker containers on this machine, thus for every smb-share one Syncthing container.

I struggle how to get the docker containers to access those directories on the host system.

---

```
    volumes:
      - /samba/userX:/userX-data
```

Simply mapping the smb-directories as volumes (with docker-compose) is a bad idea, as every file creation/modification through the docker container is done as root, therefore messes up permissions on the host (who needs correct permissions for smb).

---

```
//127.0.0.1/userX /mnt/smb/user1 cifs username=userX,password=<passwd> 0 0
```

The only solution I could think of, is to mount the SMB shares from the host system, on to the host system and then map `/mnt/smb/user` into the appropriate containers.

But this seems kind of odd to me and wouldn't unnecessarily accessing the filesystem over a network also heavily impact performance?
Or is that irrelevant as everything stays on that one physical server?

Syncthing as a storage application is recommended to have "direct" access to the storage ...

Any alternatives and ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: "every file creation/modification through the docker container is done as root" Well, no, it's done as whatever user id you've configured the container to run with. If you don't want it running as root, arrange to run it under a different uid instead.

Comment: Thank you @larsks!! I now researched a bit about the USER option for docker and this seems to be what's needed here.
But wasn't it always a drawback of docker that it only runs as root and isn't this what alternatives like Podman try to address?

Comment: In both podman and docker, the uid *inside* a container will be root by default. You can change that with the `USER` directive in your Dockerfile, or by using the `-u <uid>` option to `docker run` (or `podman run`).

Comment: I see ... but I'm sure there was some kind of "docker root problem" which is the reason why some avoid using docker. 

EDIT: "Docker daemon always runs as the root user"
But that's something else ... 

Thank you @larsks